# Comma Code - Automate the Boring Stuff

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x

I'm currently working through an exercise of [Chapter 4 from Automate the Boring Stuff](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter4/), which reads as follows:

> "Say you have a list value like this: `spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']`
>
> Write a function that takes a list value as an argument and returns a string with all the items separated by a comma and a space, with *and* inserted before the last item. For example, passing the previous `spam` list to the function would return `'apples, bananas, tofu, and cats'`. But your function should be able to work with any list value passed to it."

Since I'm an absolute beginner to Python (and programming in general), I wanted to get some advice on how to make this code cleaner. It works with any size list, but I've reviewed some other solutions on SO and it seems like there are a million ways to build this out. How can I make this more straightforward?

```
spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']

def commaCode(listVar):
    if len(listVar) == 0: # condition for an empty list
        print('There are no items in this list.') 
    
    if len(listVar) == 1: # condition for a list with 1 item
        return (str(listVar[0])+'.')

    if len(listVar) == 2: # condition for a list with 2 items
        return (str(listVar[0]) + ' and ' + str(listVar[1]) + '.')

    if len(listVar) >=3: # conditions for lists with 3+ items
        listDisp = ''
        for i in range(len(listVar[:-1])):
            listDisp = listDisp + str(listVar[i]) + ', '
        listDisp = listDisp + 'and ' + str(listVar[-1])
        return (listDisp)

commaCode(spam)
```

Comment: Ugh, that [oxford comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma)...

Comment: oxford commas are fine.  I actually find myself tending towards them more often than not these days....

Comment: I'm not sure if you are interested at all in seeing other coding languages do this (I sometimes look at other languages so I can see how things are done), but I wrote a function in PHP that does this which is only a couple of lines of code. https://eval.in/986967

Comment: As far as I can see, the task description does not require adding a dot at the end of a resulting string for a one- or two-items input list. Additionally, IMHO you don't need the separate `if len(listVar) == 2` branch; the last `if` seems able to hande the 2-items case.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. You want to look at [str.join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)
2. by the last case, `len(listVar)` is run 4 times, which is very repetitive.  Better to set it to a temporary variable, and check that each time.
3. Python has some binary convenience  operators for common things like appending.  Instead of `listDisp = listDisp + foo` use `listDisp += foo`
4. instead of calling `str()` on everything as you build the string, why not call it up front, so it can't be missed somewhere along the way.  Something at the top like `stringList = [ str(i) for i in listVar ]` will remove the need for all those `str()` calls sprinkled throughout the code.
5. Naming:  `listVar` is a variable.  It doesn't need to have 'var(iable)' in its name.  How about 'inputList'?  Names are important - they're messages to the future (you or whoever reads your code) about what you are/were trying to accomplish.  Similar issue with the name `commaCode`.
6. `range(len(listVar[:-1]))` is the same as `range(len(listVar)-1)`, which is both easier to read, and can take advantage of point 2 and end up written as `range(listVarLen-1)` which is definitely clearer.

Overall though, for a beginner, not bad!

Comment: `+=` is a binary operator, not a unary operator.

Comment: "Names are important - they're messages to the future" - well said!

Answer (score 8):

@pjz had some very good points, so I'll skip those in my review.

1. Both function names and variable names are written in `snake_case` in python.
2. Instead of printing an error message, raise an appropriate exception.
3. You append a period for input of length 1 and 2, but not for longer output.
4. Using python list slicing you can actually remove some of your special cases.

Here's two suggested improvements, one easier and one more pythonic. I also included a short testing snippet to validate that the exception is raised.

```
def comma_code(input_list):
    if len(input_list) == 0:
        # Raise an exception rather than just printing the error
        raise ValueError('List cannot be empty')
    # Convert everything to string (could also raise an exception if not string)
    string_list = [str(i) for i in input_list]
    # Handle the trivial case
    if len(string_list) == 1:
        return string_list[0]

    # This could be even more pythonic, but it would lose its readability
    more_than_two_items = len(string_list) > 2
    first_part = ', '.join(string_list[:-2])
    optional_separator = ', ' * more_than_two_items
    last_part = ', and '.join(string_list[-2:])

    formatted_string = first_part + optional_separator + last_part
    return formatted_string     

def comma_code_pythonic(input_list):
    if len(input_list) == 0:
        raise ValueError('List cannot be empty')

    string_list = [str(i) for i in input_list]

    last_part = ', and '.join(string_list[-2:])
    first_part = string_list[:-2]

    formatted_string = ', '.join(first_part + [last_part])
    return formatted_string     


# Try to place non-global variables below the function
spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']

for i in range(5):
    try:
        print("comma_code:", comma_code(spam[:i]))
    except ValueError as e:
        print(repr(e))

for i in range(5):
    try:
        print("comma_code_pythonic:", comma_code_pythonic(spam[:i]))
    except ValueError as e:
        print(repr(e))
```

Comment: Great advice. Minor nitpick: why the exception? Concatenating an empty list is an entirely valid operation. After all, `, '.join([])` in Python also works. Just return `''`.

Comment: Thank you! I included the exception because there was a similar implementation in the original question, and it seemed as if the asker was not familiar with the concept of exceptions. If i was to solve the code myself, I wouldn't include it, but if I was to print an error message, I'd raise an exception.

Answer (score 4):

This answer is less about the code you have produced, but more about how you could approach the problem if you were to do it again.

note, the python style guides promote `snake_case` over `camelCase` naming conventions, so I'll use these here.

> "Say you have a list value like this: spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
>
> Write a function that takes a list value as an argument and returns a string with all the items separated by a comma and a space, with and inserted before the last item.

What is the key functionality that needs to be done here?

Simply put, the main functionality of the code is to take the values in the list and convert this into a string.
This should immediately suggest that string.join() would be a good function for this.

As it turns out, we can join the strings with whatever sub-string we like, so by using

```
', '.join(list_of_strings)
```

we get the following transformation:

```
['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats'] -> 'apples, bananas, tofu, cats'
```

That's almost the entire task complete! ('join()' handles the 0 and 1 length list arrays correctly, so you don't have to)
We just need to insert the `'and '`.

A quick analysis of the problem shows that we only need the `'and '` when there are at least two items, so we write a modification to do just that.
We could just add `'and'` in the penultimate location in the list, but we don't want to end up with `['x', 'y'] -> 'x, and, y'` so the simple solution to this is to replace the final input in this case with `'and '` plus the input.

We can do this with one of the following lines:

```
#python 2+:
list_of_strings[-1] = 'and %s' % list_of_strings[-1]
#python 2.6+:
list_of_strings[-1] = 'and {}'.format(list_of_strings[-1])
#python 3.6+:
list_of_strings[-1] = f'and {list_of_strings[-1]}'
```

To ensure that this does not change the input (it may be reused elsewhere) we should make a copy of it first.  The simple way is to create a new list from the original:

```
list_of_strings = list(input_list_of_strings)
```

Putting this all together, we get a fairly simple function as a result:

```
def comma_code(input_list_of_strings):
    list_of_strings = list(input_list_of_strings)
    if len(list_of_strings) > 1:
        list_of_strings[-1] = f'and {list_of_strings[-1]}'
    return ', '.join(list_of_strings)
```

Comment: `list_of_strings[-1] = 'and {}'.format(list_of_strings[-1])` works in [Py2.6](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/string.html#string-formatting)+

Comment: @TemporalWolf so it does. One of my machines at work is airgapped and only runs 2.4...  I have become used to using % notation for that system. I use 3.6 everywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

To augment the other good answers already given, here's a short version that utilizes several of the already given ideas, as well as a couple additional ones:

```
>>> spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
>>> comma_code = lambda l: ", ".join(l[:-1] + ['and ' + l[-1]])
>>> comma_code(spam)
'apples, bananas, tofu, and cats'
```

The `lambda` clause is a shorthand method for defining smaller functions, rather than using the full `def ...` syntax.

It also uses list slicing, and both string and list concatenation. As long as you know your input list is only strings, this should be fine, but if you're unsure of especially the last element in the list, one of the approaches using `.format()` could be integrated just as well.

Update: just realized this will fail for lists of less than two items. So that's another assumption you'd have to make on your input. Wrapping the above in a slightly larger function that dealt with the two corner cases would be relatively easy to do.

Comment: The last comma after `tofu` makes this answer incorrect. It should be: `'apples, bananas, tofu and cats'`

Comment: @victorantunes Not by my reading of the original question, which explicitly lists the desired output as `apples, bananas, tofu, and cats`.

Comment: My bad. I totally skipped that snippet and went straight into grammar mode.

Comment: not quite.  Try `comma_code(['cats'])`  it returns `'and cats'` which should just be `cats' _true, the question doesn't explicitly state this_ but your code also throws an IndexError with an empty input list which violates _"your function should be able to work with any list value passed to it."_

Comment: @Baldrickk Hence my edit that starts with "Update:"...

Comment: @victorantunes Even in non-technical English grammar the comma after `tofu` is a well-accepted usage, the Oxford comma.

Comment: note to self: refresh old pages before commenting

Answer (score 1):

There are some excellent pointers on the other answers, but I feel that they miss the most pythonic solution:

```
def comma_code(words):
    *head, final = words

    if head:
        final = f'and {final}'

    return ', '.join(*head, final)
```

This solution should be fairly clear to any reader, and to me reads as an encoding of the problem definition: given a non-empty list of words, join them with a comma. If there are more than one, add the word 'and' before the final word.

This code does not need to special-case the empty list as the unpacking operation will raise a ValueError for an empty input. You could catch this and return an empty string if this is the desired behaviour, or you could use varadiac arguments to clarify an interface like so:

```
def comma_code_args(first, *rest):
    *head, final = first, *rest

    if head:
        final = f'and {final}'

    return ', '.join(*head, final)
```

This would be called like so:

```
>>> spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']

>>> comma_code(spam)
'apples, bananas, tofu, and cats'

>>> comma_code_args('apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats')
'apples, bananas, tofu, and cats'

>>> comma_code_args(*spam)
'apples, bananas, tofu, and cats'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
>>> print(', '.join(spam[:-2] + [spam[-2] + ' and ' + spam[-1]]))
apples, bananas, tofu and cats
```

The comma after `tofu` should not exist.

Steps:

1. `', '.join(...)` creates a comma-separated string of the values contained in `spam`
2. `spam[:-2]` slices `spam` and creates a sublist from the first to the second-to-last item. Have a look at python's [slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation).
3. `[spam[-2] + ' and ' + spam[-1]]` creates a list containing: `spam`'s second-to-last item (`'tofu'`), the word `'and'` and `spam`'s last item (`'cats'`). Creating a list is necessary because python doesn't know how to concatenate a list + another type of object. We can only concatenates lists.

---

**Edit**: [Oxford Comma](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/what-is-the-oxford-comma-and-why-do-people-care-so-much-about-it/) is a thing, apparently. Well, hooray english.

```
>>> spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
>>> print(', '.join(spam[:-1] + [' and ' + spam[-1]]))
apples, bananas, tofu, and cats
```

Comment: The comma after `tofu` is the Oxford comma. Whether to use it or not is an interesting question but moot here, because the specification includes it.

Comment: @Graipher learning something new everyday, I suppose. English isn't my first language, so my first instinct was to yell 'incorrect!'.

Comment: I can relate, in my native language (German), this would also be a mistake

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with no loops and no joins, just two `print` statements:

```
def commalist(listname):
    print(*listname[:-1], sep = ', ',end=", "),
    print('and',listname[-1])
```

the end parameter in the first `print` will determine whether to use oxford comma.

Comment: Hey Mike, could you explain in little more detail why your solution is better. The goal of Code Review isn't to just "give better code" but to explain why so the OP can learn :)